# Function not returning the value

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
A=[3,4,2,1,2,2,2,3,2,3,2,3,5,6,2]

def Sort(x):

    count=0
    for t in range(len(x)-1):
        if x[t]>x[t+1]:
            count+=1
            m,n=x[t+1],x[t]
            x[t+1],x[t]=n,m
    if count==0:
        return x
    else:
        Sort(x)

print Sort(A)
```

Comment: And what happens if `count` is 0?

Comment: then the list has been sorted , i want it to return the sorted list.. :(((

Comment: ... Then you need to return...

Comment: If you want to sort list. It's better to use more pythonic way like `sort(A)`

Comment: I just wanted to create a recursive method.. anyway thanks

Comment: Something unrelated to the problem but good to know: you don't need `m` and `n`. Use the power of tuple unpacking: `x[t], x[t+1] = x[t+1], x[t]`.

Answer (score 6):

your all branches are not returning properly.

```
count=0
for t in range(len(x)-1):
    if x[t]>x[t+1]:
        count+=1
        m,n=x[t+1],x[t]
        x[t+1],x[t]=n,m
if count==0:
    return x
else:
    return Sort(x)
```